# Unicode from localisation file are not reflecting swiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have implemented localisation of string to Japanese.

in Localization file

"madewith_string" = "\u{5fc3}\u{3092}\u{8fbc}\u{3081}\u{3066}\u{4f5c}\u{308a}\u{307e}\u{3057}\u{305f}";

```
Vstack {
    Text("madewith_string")
}

// current Output - "\u{5fc3}\u{3092}\u{8fbc}\u{3081}\u{3066}\u{4f5c}\u{308a}\u{307e}\u{3057}\u{305f}"
```

it should show `心を込めて作りました`

How can I use unicode string from localizable file?

Comment: Set like this "\U5fc3……"

Comment: @RajaKishan let me check

Answer (score 0):

Set your string formate by this

```
"madewith_string" = "\U5fc3\U3092\U8fbc\U3081\U3066\U4f5c\U308a\U307e\U3057\U305f";
```